# How to Implement Transition for AppBar Padding Based on Drawer Open/Close State in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI for my React project, and I'm trying to implement a transition for the AppBar component's paddingLeft property when a drawer is opened or closed.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I am using Redux to manage the state of the drawer (whether it's open or closed).
Based on certain conditions (like screen size and default drawer type), I determine the paddingLeft for the AppBar.
When the drawer opens, the paddingLeft of the AppBar should increase and when it closes, it should decrease.
I'd like this change in paddingLeft to have a smooth transition, but currently, the change happens abruptly.

I need a transition when drawerOpen true and when is false but nothing work for the variable paddingLeft
Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
//... [Imports and setup]

let paddingLeft;
if (matchDownMd) {
  paddingLeft = 0;
} else if (drawerOpen) {
  paddingLeft = `${DRAWER_WIDTH}px`;
} else {
  paddingLeft = `${DRAWER_WIDTH_CLOSE}px`;
}

return (
  <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <AppBar
      position="fixed"
      color="inherit"
      elevation={0}
      sx={{
        bgcolor: theme.palette.background.main,
        paddingLeft,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('paddingLeft', {
         easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
         duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
      }}
    >
      <Toolbar sx={{ p: "10px", bgcolor: "orange" }}>
        <Header />
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <Sidebar />
    <Main theme={theme} open={drawerOpen} layout={LAYOUT}>
      <Container
        maxWidth={CONTAINER ? "lg" : false}
        {...(!CONTAINER && { sx: { px: { xs: 0 }, bgcolor: "green" } })}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </Container>
    </Main>
  </Box>
);
```